# unpacking a data structure whose first byte indicates length

Tags: perl, pack

I am trying to unpack a TLE (Tagged Logical Element) from an IBM AFP format file.

The specification (http://www.afpcinc.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/MODCA-Reference-09.pdf) indicates that these are two triplets (even though there are four values) that are structured as follows (with their **byte offsets**):

**0**: Tlength | **1**: Tid | **2-n**: Parameter (= **2**: Type + **3**: Format + **4-n**: EBCDIC encoded String)

Example (with two triplets, one indicating the name and one the value):

```
0C 02  0B  00   C3 A4 99 99 85 95 83 A8    07 36  00 00    C5 E4 D9
12 KEY UID CHAR  C  u  r  r  e  n  c  y     7 VAL RESERVED  E  U  R
```

I use Perl to parse it as follows (and successfully):

```perl
            if ($key eq 'Data') {
                my $tle = $member->{struct}->{$key};
                my $k_length = hex(unpack('H2', substr($tle, 0, 1)));
                my $key = decode('cp500', substr($tle, 4, $k_length - 4));
                my $v_length = hex(unpack('H2', substr($tle, $k_length, 1)));
                my $value = decode('cp500', substr($tle, $k_length + 4, $v_length - 4));
                print("'$key' => '$value'\n");
            }
```

Result:

> 'Currency' => 'EUR'

While the above is successful, I feel that my way is a bit too cpmplicated and that there's a more efficient way to do this. E.g. do `pack` templates support reading the first *n* bytes to use as a quantifier for how many successive bytes to unpack? I read the Perl pack tutorial but can't seem to find something along those lines.

Comment: `hex(unpack('H2', substr($tle, 0, 1)))` is a weird way of writing `unpack("C", $tle)`

Comment: You're right. Why does a 'char' template yield an actual number?

Comment: Because a char is a number :)  It's an 8-bit number on modern systems, but that wasn't always the case, and might not be the case for specialized hardware. But it's 8-bits on any system on which Perl runs.

Comment: thank you. I guess the name 'char' threw me off. Good information. Anything else you'd suggest to streamline or is first reading the length, then parsing the rest the right way?

Comment: I don't think the triplets will necessarily occur in that order. Even if they must occur in that order, the description for a Tag Logical Element says that triplets other than *Fully Qualified Name* X'02' and *Attribute Value* X'36' can occur in a TLE. What I'm saying is that your overall approach of assuming you'll get only a key and a value and in that order is flawed.

Comment: that is a good point too. I can test for the 2nd byte to see which type of field we're dealing with and then parse accordingly. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the length field didn't include itself, you could do something like the following:

```
(my $record, $unparsed) = unpack("C/a a*", $unparsed);
my $key = decode("cp500", unpack("x3 a*", $record));
```

But the length field includes itself.

```
(my $length, $unparsed) = unpack("C a*", $unparsed);
(my $record, $unparsed) = unpack("a".($length-1)." a*", $unparsed);
my $key = decode("cp500", unpack("x3 a*", $record));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see if following demo code fulfill your requirements.

This code

> defines hash *decoder* subroutines
>
> reads hex representation of bytes provided by OP from *DATA* block
>
> converts read data into binary representation *$data* utilizing [pack](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html)
>
> extracts *length*, *key/tid*, *type* by utilizing [unpack](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html)
>
> call *decoder* subroutine for this particular *type*
>
> gets back hash consisting two arrays *keys* and *vals*
>
> forms new hash *%data* with provided *keys* and *vals*
>
> outputs keys and values (returned *keys* are used to preserve byte/field order)

NOTE: [Encode 'from_to'](https://perldoc.perl.org/Encode.html) is utilized to decode *EBCDIC* -- [alternative](https://perldoc.perl.org/Encode/EBCDIC.html)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use utf8;
use Encode 'from_to';

my $debug = 1;

my %decoder = ( 
                1 => \&decode_type1,
                2 => \&decode_currency,
                3 => \&decode_type3,
                4 => \&decode_type4,
                5 => \&decode_type5
            );

my $bytes = read_bytes();
my($len,$key,$type) = unpack('C3',$bytes);

my $data = $decoder{$type}($bytes);

my %data;
@data{@{$data->{keys}}} = @{$data->{vals}};

say '
 Unpacked data
---------------';
printf "%-8s => %s\n", $_, $data{$_} for @{$data->{keys}};

sub read_bytes {
    my $hex_bytes = <DATA>;

    chomp $hex_bytes;

    my $bytes = pack('H*',$hex_bytes);

    return $bytes;
}

sub show_bytes {
    my $data = shift;

    print "Bytes: ";
    printf "%02X ", $_ for unpack 'C*', $data;
    print "\n";
}

sub decode_type1 {
    my $bytes = shift;

    return { keys => 'type1', vals => 'vals1' };
}

sub decode_currency {
    my $bytes = shift;

    show_bytes($bytes) if $debug;

    my @keys = qw/length_1 key uid char data_1 length_2 val reserved data_2/;
    my @vals = unpack('C4A8C2SA3',$bytes);

    from_to($vals[4], 'cp37', 'latin1');
    from_to($vals[8], 'cp37', 'latin1');
    
    return { keys => \@keys, vals => \@vals};
}

sub decode_type3 {
    my $bytes = shift;

    return { keys => 'type3', vals => 'vals3' };
}

sub decode_type4 {
    my $bytes = shift;

    return { keys => 'type4', vals => 'vals4' };
}

sub decode_type5 {
    my $bytes = shift;

    return { keys => 'type5', vals => 'vals5' };
}

__DATA__
0C020B00C3A49999859583A807360000C5E4D9
```

Output

```
Bytes: 0C 02 0B 00 C3 A4 99 99 85 95 83 A8 07 36 00 00 C5 E4 D9

 Unpacked data
---------------
length_1 => 12
key      => 2
uid      => 11
char     => 0
data_1   => Currency
length_2 => 7
val      => 54
reserved => 0
data_2   => EUR
```

Note:

It looks suspicious that *val* occupies one byte only what gives range of 0..255 for an amount in Euro. Perhaps *reserved* bytes might be a part of the *val* amount of Euro.